# Как обновить предыдущий Activity из текущего?

Tags: java, android, activity

Android Studio 2.1.2

Есть 2 Activity, один Activity унаследован от Fragment и выводится во фрейме (назовем его A), другой от AppCompatActivity(назовем его B). Нужно после выполнения действий на ActivityB, обновить данные на ActivityA (достаточно просто его пересоздать) по нажатию на кнопку назад или на кнопку на самом ActivityB.

Открытие ActivityB осуществляется так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity( intent );
```

Comment: Activity  не может быть унаследован от Fragment. Только от Activity.

Comment: Не правильно сказал, но во фрейм я вывожу вот этот класс public class ActivityA extends Fragment
{ .. }

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо запускать активити так:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 99);
```

Далее, совершив нужные действия в запущённой активити надо её завершить, назначив результат и передав к-л данные так:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Теперь там же, где вы и запускали активити, вам надо переопределить метод `onActivityResult()`, коий будет вызван после завершения предыдущей активити и который примет результаты в качестве аргументов. Именно в этом методе вы можете изменить состояние первоначального элемента, будь то активити или фрагмент